# JQuery total sum of multiple html table cells with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table with many rows, in each row is a cell with `.sum` class, how can I calculate total sum of all cells that have `.sum` class

```js
//total sum of td with .sum class
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Desc. 1</td>
    <td class="sum">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Desc. 2</td>
    <td class="sum">27</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Desc. 3</td>
    <td class="sum">159</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over the `.sum` elements:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLn1cffs/)

```
var sum = 0;

$('#myTable .sum').each(function () {
    sum += parseInt(this.innerText);
});

alert(sum);
```

Without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qz31swds/)

```
var sum = 0,
    sumElements = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable .sum');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sumElements, function (el) {
    sum += parseInt(el.innerText);
});

alert(sum);
```